# Two Linked Lists are not being printed separately while being displayed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
public class MergeSinglyLinkedList {

private static ListNode head;

private static class ListNode {
    private int data;
    private ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

> ```
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>         MergeSinglyLinkedList sll1 = new MergeSinglyLinkedList();
>         sll1.insertAtLast(1);
>         sll1.insertAtLast(5);
>         sll1.insertAtLast(9);
>         sll1.insertAtLast(11);
>
>         MergeSinglyLinkedList sll2 = new MergeSinglyLinkedList();
>         sll2.insertAtLast(2);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(3);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(7);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(10);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(11);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(13);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(19);
>         sll2.insertAtLast(20);
>         
>         sll1.display();
>         sll2.display();
> }
> ```

```
public void insertAtLast(int value){
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(value);
    if(head==null){
        head=newNode;
        return;
    }
    ListNode current = head;
    while (null!=current.next){
        current= current.next;
    }
    current.next=newNode;
}

>     public void display(){
        ListNode current=head;
        int count=0;
        while (current!=null){
            System.out.print(current.data+"-->");
            count++;
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }
```

This is my piece of code I am trying to execute in intelliJ. The output I expect is:

```
1-->5-->9-->11-->null
2-->3-->7-->10-->11-->13-->19-->20-->null
```

But instead, the output I am getting is

> 1-->5-->9-->11-->2-->3-->7-->10-->11-->13-->19-->20-->null

I tried making a separate **display1()** function and then calling to print the Linked Lists as follwing:

```
public void display(){
        ListNode current=head;
        int count=0;
        while (current!=null){
            System.out.print(current.data+"-->");
            count++;
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }

    public void display1(){
        ListNode current=head;
        int count=0;
        while (current!=null){
            System.out.print(current.data+"-->");
            count++;
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }
```

And then calling both the functions separately as:

```
sll1.display();
sll2.display1();
```

but still, the output is:

```
1-->5-->9-->11-->2-->3-->7-->10-->11-->13-->19-->20-->null
1-->5-->9-->11-->2-->3-->7-->10-->11-->13-->19-->20-->null
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can somebody help me please?

Comment: Myguess is you are using `static` fields (i.e.`static ListNode head;`. They are global forthe class itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I did not get your point.

Comment: `head` should be a normal `MergeSinglyLinkedList` field. If you make it `static` you have a single global variable shared by all lists. Which would explain it.

Comment: Please provide the code that is needed to run this and reproduce the issue.

Comment: All the code snippet is mentioned above, please check.
'    private static ListNode head;

    private static class ListNode {
        private int data;
        private ListNode next;

        public ListNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }'

@trincot

Comment: @JoopEggen please mention the code snippet that can be used to resolve the issue?

Comment: @RishabSud, the definition of the `ListNode` class should be in your question, not in a comment. But now that you have shared `static ListNode head` ... it is clear that the first comment above is right on target. That's your problem. It means there is only one `head` even if you have multiple instances of `ListNode`. And obviously you need two heads here, not one.

Comment: oh okay, sorry I missed that part @trincot. Thanks for the solution. I will try and update accordingly.

Comment: @trincot I tried the below solution and it works for me. I have answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

> private ListNode head;
>
> ```
> private static class ListNode {
>     private int data;
>     private ListNode next;
>
>     public ListNode(int data) {
>         this.data = data;
>         this.next = null;
>     }
> }
> ```

There is only one head even if I have multiple instances of ListNode because in definition of head, `static` keyword is used. Hence if we make another `ListNode head` or remove the `static` from the existing defintion, the output will be as follows:

> 1-->5-->9-->11-->null
> 2-->3-->7-->10-->11-->13-->19-->20-->null